# How to safely abandon an ubuntu session?

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to migrate a huge database into an Ubuntu 18.04 server but is there a way that even if i was to lose the connection(vpn or ssh) somehow, it will keep running the migration in the background and i can attach that session when i reconnect and ssh back in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do things like run scripts in the background or stop a running job with `Ctrl-Z` and continue it in the background by the `bg` command. But you will want to have your jobs outputting sensibly to logs etc so you can go back and check progress etc. Have a search for `nohup`, `bg` etc. Such as [this link](https://hexadix.com/use-nohup-execute-commands-background-keep-running-exit-shell-promt/) which was the first I found.

Answer (score 1):

The `screen` and `tmux` applications are *terminal multiplexers*

You can run virtual terminals, and attach/detach without disturbing the ongoing process.

Both are in the Ubuntu repositories.